# SQL join add missing data for time and identifier

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables:
Table a containing values per c_id per minute. (If data is missing for c_id and minute - row is missing).

Table a:

```
---------------------------------
| c_id  | TIME_SEC    | C_VALUE |
---------------------------------
|    1  | 1431943200  |      10 |
---------------------------------
|    1  | 1431943260  |      11 |
---------------------------------
|    2  | 1431943200  |      12 |
---------------------------------
```

table times containing all minutes:

```
------------
| TIME_SEC |
------------
|1431943140|
------------
|1431943200|
------------
|1431943260|
------------
|1431943320|
------------
```

I want to get all data in a including missing data for given c_ids between times. For example for:
c_id in (1,2) and TIME_SEC between 1431943140 and 1431943320

The expected result is:

```
---------------------------------
| c_id  | TIME_SEC    | C_VALUE |
---------------------------------
|    1  | 1431943140  |    null |
---------------------------------
|    1  | 1431943200  |      10 |
---------------------------------
|    1  | 1431943260  |      11 |
---------------------------------
|    1  | 1431943320  |    null |
---------------------------------
|    2  | 1431943140  |    null |
---------------------------------
|    2  | 1431943200  |      12 |
---------------------------------
|    2  | 1431943260  |    null |
---------------------------------
|    2  | 1431943320  |    null |
---------------------------------
```

Adding missing data to table a is not an option as it adds huge amount of data.

I tried to use this SQL:

```
select * 
from 
(
select * from 
a where c_id IN ( 1,2 ) AND TIME_SEC between 1431943140 and 1431943320
) m 
right join times t
on (m.TIME_SEC = t.TIME_SEC);
```

But it returns missing data per minute globally - for all c_id:

```
---------------------------------
| c_id  | TIME_SEC    | C_VALUE |
---------------------------------
| null  | 1431943140  |    null |
---------------------------------
|    1  | 1431943200  |      10 |
---------------------------------
|    1  | 1431943260  |      11 |
---------------------------------
|    2  | 1431943200  |      12 |
---------------------------------
| null  | 1431943320  |    null |
---------------------------------
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Create a derived table of desired c_id and times, and then LEFT JOIN it to the values:

```
select m.c_id, m.TIME_SEC, a.C_VALUE
from (
  SELECT DISTINCT a.c_id, t.TIME_SEC
  FROM a
  CROSS JOIN times t
  where a.c_id IN ( 1,2 ) AND t.TIME_SEC between 1431943140 and 1431943320
) m
LEFT OUTER JOIN a
  ON m.c_id=a.c_id
  AND m.TIME_SEC=a.TIME_SEC;
```

Comment: Your `where` clause turns the `left join` into an `inner join`.

Comment: Right you are.   Edited and fixed, I think.

Comment: It doesn't give null values.

Comment: edited again to use CROSS JOIN, but I am not sure if it's the correct syntax for MySQL.   This would work for SQL Server.

Comment: Now it returns duplicate values, but this is the right direction. Thanx!

Comment: What's getting duplicated?   I'm not seeing how it could return duplicates.

Comment: You should add distinct  a.c_id.

Comment: ah ok.  That makes sense.   Again I'm not sure of MySQL syntax, but edited the way I would do it in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

First generate all the rows using `cross join`.  Then bring in the additional values:

```
select c.c_id, t.time_sec, a.c_value
from (select 1 as c_id union all select 2) c cross join
     (select distinct time_sec
      from a
      where c_id in (1, 2) and time_sec between 1431943140 and 1431943320
     ) t left join
     a
     on a.c_id = c.c_id and a.time_sec = t.time_sec;
```

EDIT:

If you want to use the `times` table:

```
select c.c_id, t.time_sec, a.c_value
from (select 1 as c_id union all select 2) c cross join
     times t left join
     a
     on a.c_id = c.c_id and a.time_sec = t.time_sec;
```

I am not sure if the `where` clause limiting times is needed or not.